# How to Set Jgroups UDP to unicast instead of default multicast in standalone-ha.xml

Tags: udp, jboss7.x, wildfly, jgroups, unicast

Jgroups use "IP multicasting by default to send messages to all members (UDP) and for discovery of the initial members . However, if multicasting cannot be used, the UDP  can be configured to send multiple unicast messages instead of one multicast message. To configure UDP to use multiple unicast messages to send a group message instead of using IP multicasting, the ip_mcast property has to be set to false." (as per jboss documentation https://developer.jboss.org/ )

My question is how can I pass "ip_mcast" value to false in wildfly? Below is the sample jgroups subsystem in the standalone-ha.xml. In the xsd I don't see a way to pass this value. Please help!!

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:4.0">
      <channels default="ee">
        <channel name="ee" stack="udpgossip"/>
      </channels>
      <stacks>
        <stack name="udpgossip">
          <transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
          <protocol type="TCPGOSSIP">
            <property name="initial_hosts">172.17.0.2[12001]</property>
        </protocol>
          <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
          <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
          <protocol type="FD"/>
          <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
          <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2"/>
          <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
          <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
          <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
          <protocol type="MFC"/>
          <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
        </stack>
      </stacks>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the schema, `<transport/>` extends `<protocol/>`, and protocols can have properties, as your config sample already shows. So the correct way to set it should be

```
<transport type="UDP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp">
    <property name="ip_mcast">false</property>
</transport>
```